# JavaScript: How can I insert an Object into an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this script that takes data from a JSON with almost 100 data, then uses this data to bring the weather from an API and after that, inserts this data into an object (using a `for` for creating my 100 objects), I would like to add the objects that have a `temperature > 99` in one array and the ones that have a `temperature < 99` into another I have tried this way but doesn't seem to work, sorry if it's a super fool mistake that I can't see, thanks for your help!

This is my script:

```
async function calcWeather(){ 
    const info = await fetch('../json/data.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }); 
    for (var i in info) {
        const _idOficina = info[i][0].IdOficina
        const _nombreOficina = info[i][0].NombreOficinaSN
        const _zona = info[i][0].Zona
        const _estado = info[i][0].NombreEstado
        const lat = info[i][0].latjson 
        const long = info[i][0].lonjson 
        const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`
        fetch(base)
        .then((responses) => {
            return responses.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            // console.log(data)
            var myObject = { 
                Id_Oficina: _idOficina,  
                Latitud: data.coord.lat,
                Longitud: data.coord.lon,
                Ciudad: data.name, 
                Estado: _estado,
                Zona: _zona,
                Nombre_Oficina: _nombreOficina,
                Temperatura: data.main.temp, 
                Descripcion: data.weather[0].description
            };  
            // validation
            if (myObject.Temperatura < 99){
                var lstValid = [];
                function pushValid(){
                    lstValid.push(myObject[i]);
                }
                pushValid();
                console.log(pushValid())
            }
        });   
    }    
};
```

Comment: What do you think `myObject[i]` refers to? Also, you reset `lstValid` to an empty array every time you find an object with a low temperature, losing anything you had already pushed in.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you answer my first question?

Comment: I'm sorry mate, `myObject[i]` refers to the object I'm creating with the data I have, but the object doesnt need the `[i]` I havent see it

Comment: `i` is defined elsewhere in your code and refers to a property/index of `info`. So what would be the value you expect `myObject[i]` to be? Quite likely `myObject[i]` is undefined. This kind of things you can find out yourself by using a debugger.

Comment: You should consider mapping from each info to a promise representing a fetch of the weather for that info, then await all the promises, then map all the results to your custom objects, then filter the resulting custom objects by temperature range (twice: once for < 99, once for >= 99).

Comment: 1. you need to declare `var lstValid = [];` somewhere outside all that; right now it only exists inside the callback and ends up being created over and over again, each time filled with a single object, then discarded. The contents of the if block in general needs to be fixed; all you need in there is `lstValid.push(myObject);`.

Comment: Yes, It was my mistake, I changed `myObject[i]` to `myObject`  I was expecting the value to be the Object, with all the attributes

Comment: If I had to do this I'd 1. load all objects 2. use map() to change them 3. finally, sort them into the two arrays.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'll try it :)

Comment: @ChrisG My code was a mess, thanks mate I did what you said and worked, thanks to everyone too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is local, so for every object you create new `lstValid` array with no previous data. The solution is to create the array **before** fetching the data or before the loop:

```
async function calcWeather(){
    var lstValid = []; // HERE
    const info = await fetch('../json/data.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }); 
    var lstValid = []; // OR HERE (ONLY ONE OF THEM)
   for (...) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: It was a horrible mistake I was doing, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably be best served by creating the array outside of that call since you're clearing it every run. Then simply add your object. Like Trincot's comment, i'm not sure what exactly you're indexing.

```
async function calcWeather(){
    var lstValid = [];
    ....
   
    if (myObject.Temperatura < 99){
        lstValid[someindex] = myObject;
    }
    else{
        lstNotValid[someOtherIndex] = myObject;
    }
}
```